# Not able to access public properties of parent component in props passed function in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Not able to access public properties of parent component in props passed function in angular.When the function hit "setEntradaMain" in the child component it console "entrada" in the parent its showing undefined. even I have tried with event emmiter its giving the same output.I have place my code below:--

```
<!--- parent component  -->
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reserva-contrato-modal',
  templateUrl: './reserva-contrato-modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reserva-contrato-modal.page.scss'],
})
export class ReservaContratoModalPage implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}
  constructor() {}
  public field="";
  public observation="";
  public fieldText="";
  public tabId = 'bookings';
  public nameTab = 'entrada';
  public stepUrl = '';
  public buttonTitle = '';
  public entrada:Object = {
    limpiezaEntrada: '',
    pinturaEntrada: '',
    sueloEntrada: '',
    ventanaEntrada: '',
    persianasEntrada: '',
    puertaEntrada: '',
    cerraduraEntrada: '',
    iluminacionEntrada: '',
    radiadoresEntrada: '',
    telefonilloEntrada: '',
    mobiliarioEntrada: '',
    observacionesLimpiezaEntrada: '',
    observacionesPinturaEntrada: '',
    observacionesSueloEntrada: '',
    observacionesVentanaEntrada: '',
    observacionesPersianasEntrada: '',
    observacionesPuertaEntrada: '',
    observacionesCerraduraEntrada: '',
    observacionesIluminacionEntrada: '',
    observacionesRadiadoresEntrada: '',
    observacionesTelefonilloEntrada: '',
    observacionesMobiliarioEntrada: '',
  };
  changeTab(tabName) {
    this.nameTab = tabName;
  }
  setEntrada(field: any, observation: any, fieldText: any):void {
    console.log(this.entrada);

  }
 
}

<!--- Passed Props function (setEntrada) ------->

  <app-entrada-hall [setEntrada]="setEntrada" ></app-entrada-hall>


<!---- child component. --->

import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-entrada-hall',
  templateUrl: './entrada-hall.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../../../pages/bookings/new-booking-modal/new-booking-modal.page.scss',
    './entrada-hall.component.scss',
  ],
})
export class EntradaHallComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() setEntrada: (param1: string, param2: string, param3: string) => void;
  // @Output() $setEntrada = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor() {}
  public limpiezaEntrada: boolean;
  ngOnInit() {}

  setEntradaMain(field: any,  observasion:any, fieldText: any,) {
    this.setEntrada(field,observasion, fieldText);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is the way you are calling parent function in child, this is related to how `this` works in javascript.
when you passed parent component's method to child and called that method in child like this:
`this.setEntrada(field,observasion, fieldText)`
that method's context or you can say `this` is pointing to child component not parent and therefore you are not able to access parent component's properties.
Solution is pretty simple, you need to first bind the context to the parent component's method before passing it to child, this is how you can do it:

```js
export class ReservaContratoModalPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(/* your dependencies... */) {
    this.setEntrada = this.setEntrada.bind(this);
  }
```

now when you call this method from anywhere, it'll refer to that `ReservaContratoModalPage` whenever you use `this` keyword.